# How to modifiy Assembly parameter using Data Management API?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am currently working on design-automation-csharp-inventor example, and it works fine with the modification of part(.ipt) parameter. Is there any way to change the (.iam) parameters? What changes should be done in config.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [design.automation.inventor-csharp-basics](https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/design.automation.inventor-csharp-basics) sample already handles both assembly and part documents and depending on which one is loaded it will change parameters in the appropriate document.

So it does change parameters in the [BoxAssembly](https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/design.automation.inventor-csharp-basics/blob/master/Solution/clientApp/inputFiles/BoxAssembly.zip) as well.

You just have to change what assembly parameter you are changing by modifying line #442 in this file [Program.cs](https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/design.automation.inventor-csharp-basics/blob/master/Solution/clientApp/Program.cs)

Also, in the meantime we created a step-by-step guide on using the Design Automation API for Inventor which should make it easier to understand what you need to change to achieve what you need: [LearnForge](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/modifymodels)